# How can I check how many Python versions are installed?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, python

Is there a single command to show which versions of Python are installed in Ubuntu 14.04?

I know that if I type `python --version` or `python3 --version` I'll get the version of either one, but is there a command that will tell me all the versions that are currently installed at once?

Thanks

Comment: Does "whereis python" work for you ?

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: @ParsaMousavi `whereis python` does give a good answer. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this question is *specific* to 14.04 which is the criterion we use to decide whether EoL questions are off topic (this is different from our policy on Ubuntu derivatives and other non-Ubuntu distros which are always off topic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a command called [whereis](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis) which does that for you :

```
 whereis python
```